# If I hack a maximal sequence into another sequence, is it maximal and can I derive the primitive for it?

Tags: number-theory

Given a maximal sequence generated by an LFSR - I would like to perform the following post-processing on the sequence:

- If a specific bit is `0` - discard the number completely.
- Remove the bit (must always be a `1` now) with a simple shift.

It is well known that maximal sequences generated by LFSRs are easy to predict because given enough numbers in the sequence you can derive the primitive polynomial being used.

Is the result of the above adjustments to the sequence another maximal sequence? If so can it be generated by an LFSR, and if so can the primitive polynomial for it be derived from the new sequence?

For example - taking a 4-bit sequence and using the leftmost bit for the above process (i.e. if leftmost bit is `0` discard the whole value, otherwise just remove that bit).

```
1111 -> 111
1110 -> 110
1100 -> 100
1000 -> Discard - I think, because 000.
0001 -> Discard
0010 -> Discard
0100 -> Discard
1001 -> 001
0011 -> Discard
0110 -> Discard
1101 -> 101
1010 -> 010
0101 -> Discard
1011 -> 011
0111 -> Discard
```

resulting in the sequence

```
111
110
100
001
101
010
011
```

Comment: Maximal sequences tend to consist of $2^n-1$ terms, of which $2^{n-1}$ are odd ones (since the pure-zeros state is a fixed point of the LFSR); leading to a sequence which includes pure-zeros term -- so it couldn't be a maximal-sequence of an LFSR. I might be misunderstanding your proposed approach, though -- so it might be a good idea to add a small (e.g. $3$ or $4$-bit), worked-out example of an LFSR producing maximal sequence, followed by the effect of your post-processing on it.

Comment: @PeterKošinár - Thank you for the suggestion - example added.